# How do you get the text from a label and store it as a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp ListView displaying the data of all users in a SQL table. I want to be able to click a button beside the users details to store their UserID in a variable for further use.

[image]

I have no idea how to get the label text from the selected user and store it as a variable in the C# code behind file.

**Front End:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr style="">
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("User_Id") %>' runat="server" ID="User_IdLabel" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("User_Firstname") + " " +  Eval("User_Surname") %>' runat="server" ID="User_NameLabel" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("User_Email") %>' runat="server" ID="User_EmailLabel" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <asp:CheckBox Checked='<%# Eval("User_ScrumMaster") %>' runat="server" ID="User_ScrumMasterCheckBox" Enabled="false" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <asp:CheckBox Checked='<%# Eval("User_Developer") %>' runat="server" ID="User_DeveloperCheckBox" Enabled="false" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <asp:CheckBox Checked='<%# Eval("User_ProductOwner") %>' runat="server" ID="User_ProductOwnerCheckBox" Enabled="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="AddUserButton" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" runat="server" Text="Add User" onclick="AddUserButton_Click"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void AddUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String projectId = Request.QueryString["Project_id"];
    String userId = this.User_NameLabel.Text;
    // INSERT INTO ProjectTeam WHERE Project_Id = projectId AND User_Id = userId etc.;
}
```

I'm really at a loss here all the solutions I've looked up involve only static data and I'm really not sure what to do. Thanks in advance for any help you  can provide.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39377507/5836671. Basically you send the ID as a `CommandArgument` along with the button.

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you very much, I seem to have gotten it working now

Answer (score 0):

In your ASPX add a `CommandArgumand` attribute to your button that will hold the user id:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddUserButton" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" 
runat="server" Text="Add User" onclick="AddUserButton_Click" 
Commandargument="<%# Eval("User_Id") %>"/>
```

In your code behind, use the value passed in the `CommandArgument`:

```
protected void AddUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String projectId = Request.QueryString["Project_id"];
    String userId = e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I think I've got it working now.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted, if this is not the case, please post your own answer with the solution you used.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing     **Button button = (sender as Button) and String userId = button.CommandArgument** in your code.
you can try following to make it working.

```
 <asp:Button ID="AddUserButton" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" 
    runat="server" Text="Add User" onclick="AddUserButton_Click" 
    Commandargument="<%# Eval("User_Id") %>"/>

    protected void AddUserButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String projectId = Request.QueryString["Project_id"];
     Button button = (sender as Button);
        String userId = button.CommandArgument;
    }
```